# How to remove next equal elements in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove element in array, if this element equal previous element.

We have array `[3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1]`

How to combine elements and get such an array as `[3,2,5,1,7,1] from [3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1]`?

```
[3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1] => [3,2,5,1,7,1]
```

> update:

what if I need array like this:

```
[3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1] => [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]]
```

Get counts of elements which were deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#filter` is probably the best way to go here. Just for old times sake here's the imperative style.

```js
let arr = [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]].flat();

for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i-1] === arr[i]) arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr)
```

EDIT:
You can also keep counts. It's a little wordier but here you go. For this particular problem, you need a different approach.

```js
function splitCounts(arr) {
  let res = [];
  let count = 1;

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i+1]) {
      count++;
    } else {
      res.push([arr[i], count]);
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

// [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]]
console.log(splitCounts([3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1]));
```

Comment: Yes, you just need to flatten it. I'll update my answer

Comment: no no no, I need  [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]] from flatten array

Comment: [3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1] => [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]]

Comment: @AlexLatro Oh I see. Yeah sure I've added it to my answer

Answer (score 3):

You could do with `Array#filter` method `arr[i-1] = a` check the previous elem is same

```js
const arr = [3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1];

const res =  arr.filter((a,i)=> arr[i-1] != a);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you show what would be code if I need join this elements like [3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1] => [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]]

Comment: @AlexLatro what is the combination on start `[3,1]` . 2nd element is 2. But your array is 1 . can you check ?

Comment: [3,1] = 3 is element value, 1 is count of elements after reduce. [3,[2,2],5,[1,2],7,1] - this is reduced array. [2,2] - ["element value", "count of elements"]